# coffeescript chaining calls

Tags: coffeescript, method-chaining

Couldn't manage chaining calls using coffee script.
I'm trying to reproduce this in coffee script:

```
function htmlEscape(str) {
    return String(str)
        .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
        .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
        .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
        .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
        .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```

I'm trying this way:

```
htmlEscape = (str) ->
    String(str)
    .replace (a,b)
    .replace (c,d)
```

receiving an `Parse error on line 13: Unexpected ','` error.
Could anyone help me with the proper chaining syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must remove these spaces (and probably put an space after the comma):

```
htmlEscape = (str) ->
    String(str) 
    .replace(a, b) 
    .replace(c, d)
```

Or:

```
htmlEscape = (str) ->
    String(str).
      replace(a, b). 
      replace(c, d)
```

I like the second. Note you can abstract what you are doing using `reduce`.

Comment: I'm still getting [link](http://s9.postimage.org/z6moguo8f/Untitled.png)the error[/link] using the 2nd method.

Comment: I c&p and I didn't noticed, but why I are you writing an space between function and arguments?

Comment: Thanks. the space between the function name and the arguments was the problem.